# Postfix header checks multiple actions

Tags: postfix-mta

I want to make a header check rule to add a reply-to and change From to a no-reply.
I use it for sort of diffusion list adress

I have tried this regexp code but it is not working:

```
if !/^From:(.+@myserver\.fr)/
/^From:(.*)$/ PREPEND Reply-To:$1
/^From:(.*)$/ REPLACE From: no-reply@myserver.fr
endif
```

Only the first action is use.

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your match regex. You are matching the same header twice and thats not possible with header checks.
if you can set the reply to in the `email client` you can just replace the from address with header checks and the case is solved.

```
if !/^From:(.+@myserver\.fr)/
/^From:(.*)$/ REPLACE From: no-reply@myserver.fr
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is a problem with your solution:
the `$1` will not be matched by the Subject, so I don't know what to `PREPEND` with `Reply-To`

Comment: Thanks again, but this time the problem is that I loose the `Reply-To` part which is quite embarassing :)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way that I found to fix something similar like this was, creating two files with regex sentences, to do this I edited the main.cf and I added these two files:

```
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/add_original_rcpt.pcre
```

and I put one regex sentence in each file, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Replace From header

The above syntax looks wrong try as below,enable header_checks with postfix main.cf

Append the lines as below in header_checks file,Next if u want to add Reply_To header next to From header,do as below

/^From:[[:space:]]+(.*)/ REPLACE From:  noreply@domain.com,

> Prepend or Add new Header .* explains next to

/^From:.*/ PREPEND Reply_To: xyz@domain.com

If you want to set return path set using canonical_maps